# Moment of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with finite $k$th moment, $k\geq1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to prove that $X+Y$ has finite $k$th moment.

I don't know how to approach this question, since we know nothing about the probability density function of $X+Y$. Doing a little bit of research, I have found that the pdf of $X+Y$ is the convolution of the pdfs of $X$ and $Y$. However, I should be able to prove the statement without knowing this. I know we can bound $|X+Y|^k$ by $2^{k-1}(|X|^k + |Y|^k)$, but I don't see how this help to bound
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |X+Y|^k f_{X+Y}
$$
where $f_{X+Y}$ is the pdf of $X+Y$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathbb E[\vert X+Y\vert^k\vert]\le\mathbb E[2^{k-1}(\vert X\vert^k+\vert Y\vert^k)]=2^{k-1}(\mathbb E[\vert X^k\vert]+\mathbb E[\vert Y^k\vert])<+\infty.
$$

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you very much.